# HTML 5 version used by current gen. of browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, html, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I am looking to find out what version of HTML 5 is been used by current generation of browsers. Any one has any links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 is not a full specification yet. It's still work in progress... Different browsers implement different HTML5 features.

[Here](http://html5test.com/)'s a quick way to determine which features are supported by different browsers and which not.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am more interested in finding out about which browsers currently support HTML Media Capture interface (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#captureparam) but HTML5Test.com showing abbreviations (WebM, Ogg Vorbis etc) that I don't understand. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean the capture attribute for the input element, sorry but didn't hear anything about that yet. As far as I know, it's not something browsers have come up with yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are versions of HTML5...

Each browser accept different parts of it, but all tags and attributes are set in stone for the moment. I don't remember seeing an HTML 5.x floating around.

Comment: "all tags and attributes are set in stone" [citation needed] (I'm not saying that's false, I'm just wondering where you got that piece of info)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

And I don't think we wouldn't hear about a new tag just popping up without a new version of HTML... the browsers already have such a hard time to keep up...

Comment: I don't see any reference to attributes and tags "set in stone". As far as that link is concerned, that could be the *current* proposed tags/attributes. I mean, it's not even a Candidate Recommendation yet.

Comment: The elements are definitely not set in stone. `<time>` has been in, out, and in again over the last few weeks. The future of `<data>` and `<hgroup>` remains in doubt and it's quite likely that other semantics-only elements like `<time>` will be added quite shortly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML5, just HTML.

http://ishtml5readyyet.com/

http://www.modernizr.com/